# How to reuse common fragment views in other fragment class?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I created a GridView menu in my FragmentA class and also I created a separate Common_Fragment class which is contain two ImageView. Now I want to reuse those Common_Fragment views in my FragmentA class and other Fragment. How can I do this?

```css
My FragmentA class

public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

 public FragmentA() {
  // Required empty public constructor
 }

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // Inflate the layout for this fragment
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
  
  CommonFragment fragment = new CommonFragment();
  FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
  transaction.add(R.id.dynamicFragmentLayout, fragment);
  transaction.commit();
  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.dynamicFragmentLayout, new Fragment()).commit();

 

  return view;
 }

}
```

```css
Common_Fragment Class

public class CommonFragment extends Fragment {
 ImageView imageView1,imageview2;
 
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.common_fragment,
    container, false);
  
  imageView1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
 
  
  return view;

}
}
```

```css
fragment_a.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dynamicFragmentLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

```css
common_fragment.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/dynamicFragmentLayout" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black" 
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I used this code in FragmentB

```css
This is my FragmentB Class

public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

 public FragmentB() {
  // Required empty public constructor
 }

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // Inflate the layout for this fragment
  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
 
  CommonFragment fragment = new CommonFragment();
  FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
  transaction.add(R.id.dynamicFragmentLayout, fragment);
  transaction.commit();
  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new CommonFragment()).commit();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a container in the layout xml of `FragmentA` and load the `common_fragment` into that `FragmentA`.

**In fragment_a.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></FrameLayout>
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        .........
 />
```

**In the FragmentA.java**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
         //Add the fragment
         getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(new             CommonFragment(),R.id.container).commit();        
          //Your code.  
    }
```